# docker sql error - invalid ELF header (Possible cause: endianness mismatch)

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, java-11

My docker file contains:

```
FROM  maven:3.8.5-adoptopenjdk-11

WORKDIR /Project
COPY /Proj_Copy/ /Project/
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/Project/test.jar", "excel", "/Project/."]
```

Within my test.jar file, we interact with SQL queries and I am packaging 64bit dll files along with my other project files and pointing my code to that jar within container. I keep getting the following error:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /Project/jars/sqljdbc_auth.dll which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Project/jars/sqljdbc_auth.dll: /Project/jars/sqljdbc_auth.dll: invalid ELF header (Possible cause: endianness mismatch)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2442)
```

Comment: A DLL is a Windows library, whereas ELF is the library format used practically everywhere else. In other words, whatever operating system you’re using here, it doesn’t seem to be Windows, but an operating system expecting native libraries to be in the ELF format. So you can’t use a DLL with this operating system.

Comment: @Holger i didn't specify any OS at all at my end as you can see in docker file content. I am indeed executing this from my windows laptop, not sure if that means anything at all. I am still not sur how to overcome this issue.

Comment: Whether you specify an operating system or not, the docker image will have one. The error message clearly indicates that it is one that expected a library in the  ELF format. The type of the host OS is irrelevant.